# Applying mapping to strings

Tags: python, function, mapping

I have the following function that counts the number of consonants for each word:

```
def number_of_consonants(words):
    
    consonant_list = [len([letter for letter in word if letter.lower() not in 'aeiou']) \
            for word in words.split()]
    return print(consonant_list)
```

Suppose I have a simple text

```
text= "eventually renamed Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope years later"
```

Applying the function generates the desired result

```
number_of_consonants(text)
[6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

However, if when I try to use the mapping function on the same text, I get an entirely different output. For example

```
result = map(number_of_consonants, text)
list(result)

sample output generated:
[0]
[1]
[0]
[1]
...
None, 
None
```

How do I get the same output as the function output?

Thanks

Comment: **1.** `return print(consonant_list)` does nothing useful. Print first (if you need to) and then return. **2.** You missed pasting the line of code where yo did the split. **3.** `def number_of_consonants(words):` indicates that you did the split on the text already. Same rule applies when you use it with `map()`. You're using `words` for `number_of_consonants` but using `text` for `map(number_of_consonants, text)`.

Comment: `map(number_of_consonants, text.split(' '))`.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a sequence, so when you call `map`, you're applying the function to each character in the string.

You need to perform the splitting beforehand, so that you perform the `map` on the list of words.